# With SAX Parser, get an attribute's value

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser, xml-attribute

I am parsing XML from the web using Android. The code below shows a sample of the XML. The problem I'm having is I can't get the string value of the item tag. When I use `name = attributes.getQName(i);` it outputs the name, not the value of the attribute.

```
<weatherdata>
 <timetags>
  <item name="date">
   <value>20/04/2012</value>
   <unit/>
   <image/>
   <class>dynamic</class>
   <description>The current date</description>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use

```
attributes.getValue(i);
```

instead of

```
attributes.getQName(i);
```

because as [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/AttributesImpl.html#getQName%28int%29) says :

**getQName** :*Return an attribute's qualified (prefixed) name.*

**getValue** : *Look up an attribute's value by qualified (prefixed) name.*

see [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/sax/get-element-attributes-in-sax-xml-parsing) example for getting attribute name and value

Answer (score 14):

```
 @Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
     if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
        //currentMessage.setMediaUrl(attributes.getValue(BaseFeedParser.Url));
                     String valueis=attributes.getValue("name")
    }
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `attributes.getValue(i)` method